# Why "even number of elements in Group" in this question is given?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove one question about group.

"If finite group G has identity e and even number of elements, prove that there is "a" (not equal to "e") such that $a*a=e$."

I just don't understand why Group has to have even numbers and it seems to me that if i just 
let $a$ be inverse of $a$ itself, then $a*a=e$.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You can't just "let" $a$ be its own inverse. There may not be such an element besides the identity. In fact, take *any* finite group you know with an odd number of elements and you can check by direct calculation that it has no solution to $a^2 = e$ other than the identity. In other words, the condition that $G$ have even order is not just sufficient for the equation $a^2 = e$ to have a solution besides the identity, but it is necessary as well.

Comment: For the simplest counterexample, suppose that $G$ consists of a single element.

Comment: If $a^2 \neq e$, then $a \neq a^{-1}$ i.e., each element with order $\neq 2$, can be paired with its inverse. That leaves one identity $e \in G$ and since $|G|$ is even, there must be an odd number of order $2$ elements, i.e., atleast one order $2$ element.

Comment: About half the questions on this site about [groups with elements of order 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=group+++elements+of+order+2) are closely related to your question.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: If $g\in G$ and $g^2\ne e$, set the pair $\{g,g^{-1}\}$ aside. Keep doing this until you run out of elements that are not their own inverses. What's left if the order of $G$ is even? (And what might be the only thing left if the order of $G$ is odd?)